# Vector returning NULL values

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having an issue with getting my vector to return with data. I'm passing in a vector to `getAudioStreams` that'll hold the data I want, but when I print out the values, they're all empty. In `getAudioStreams`, I have a pointer for an array of the values, but after each loop the value in the vector becomes NULL.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue of scope, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Thanks for any help!

Main.cpp

```
std::vector<WCHAR*> names;
mvc.getAudioStreams(names);
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
{
    printf("Main I: %d | %ls\n", i, names.at(i));
}
```

MainVolumeControl.cpp

```
void MainVolumeControl::getAudioStreams(std::vector<WCHAR*>& o_streams)
{
    ...
    WCHAR* progName;
    int nSessionCount = 5;
    for (int n = 0; n < nSessionCount; n++)
    {
        ...
        WCHAR wsImageName[MAX_PATH + 1];
        DWORD nSize = MAX_PATH;
        if (QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, NULL, wsImageName, &nSize))
        {
            printf("\nImage: %ls\n", wsImageName);
            progName = extractName(wsImageName);
            printf("Prog: %ls\n\0", progName);
            o_streams.push_back(progName);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < o_streams.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("I: %d | %ls\n", i, o_streams.at(i));
        printf("\n");
    }

}

WCHAR* MainVolumeControl::extractName(WCHAR i_imageName[])
{
    constexpr u_int LEN_IMAGE_MAX = MAX_PATH + 1;
    WCHAR o_progName[LEN_IMAGE_MAX];

    ... // Extracting the name from a longer string

    return o_progName;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ char array gives strange output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473199/c-char-array-gives-strange-output)

Comment: Thou shalt not return a reference to a local variable. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when returned and then immediately go out of scope and expire, leaving you with a pointer to a dead array. Shouldn't get a NULL pointer out of this though.

Comment: Start by changing `std::vector<WCHAR*> names;` to `std::vector< std::wstring> names;` and the rest should follow.

Comment: @user4581301   It appears that the OP is not comparing the pointer with null, instead interpreting "no apparent output with `%s` format" as meaning a null pointer.  Although the behaviour is undefined, a common result in such a case is no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @JaMit & @Richard Critten!

Returning a value instead of using pointers/references solved the issue.
Using std::wstring instead of WCHAR* cleaned up my code a decent bit too